# swift for windows platform and linux platform development

Tags: swift

As I known Cocotron GNUStep are the objectivec sdk for windows and linux.
Just wonder if apple's new language  Swift can work with Cocotron GNUStep on windows and linux.

Your comment welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Currently Apple distributes Swift as part of Xcode6 betas, which only work on OS X. There are hints that Swift will be open sourced when it is finished, at which point it is up to the community to port it to different platforms. No doubt that will happen.

Answer (score 1):

Apple open-sourced Swift earlier this year and has recently announced a [Linux port](https://swift.org/blog/swift-linux-port/) (64-bit only). However it says that one needs to build an app using Xcode on OSX if you want to submit it to the App Store.